# Why does this generate 1 table when it should obviously generate 2?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, android-studio

So I'm working on a project in Android Studio and I came across unexpected behaviour from the SQLite built in library.
I'm writing code which at least should generate 2 tables one being users and the other being weightTable and it only generates users.

I came across another question which said that execSQL only takes one statement, but conjoining the 2 tables into one execSQL didn't seem to work either

Code:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "Login.db";

    public DBHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context,DB_NAME,null,1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase myDB) {

        myDB.execSQL("create Table users(username TEXT primary key, password TEXT)"); 
        myDB.execSQL("create Table weightTable(username TEXT,date TEXT, weight INT)");


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase myDB, int i, int i1) {
       myDB.execSQL("drop Table if exists users");
       myDB.execSQL("drop Table if exists weightTable");

    }
}
```

There are other methods for inserting and extracting data which are not relevant for this question so they will be left out.

Comment: You have a syntax error in the `onUpgrade` method.  Still, please provide specific detail, the exact error.  Notice there's nothing wrong with the `create table` syntax.  So the error is likely elsewhere.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=17f8c444080ecf753332fe970b1de29d

Comment: I have error checking in Android Studio itself and besides I believe the app simply won't run if you have a syntax error.

The reason it's there is because the original code is too obfuscated already so I typed it in Stack Overflow and apparently made a typo. 
Is there any other reason you can think of for this not working correctly?

Comment: It looks reasonable.  If you're seeing no errors, maybe the table is created and later dropped.  How did you decide the table is not created?

Comment: Because when opening the database itself be it in Android Studio itself or another software only the users table shows.

Comment: Also I only came to check that because when trying to insert to the weightTable it throws a "no such table" exception...

Comment: Sure.  But that doesn't mean the `create` failed.  That could mean the table was later dropped.  Can you show the exact error generated when the `create` failed?